# Plotting regression line

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

I have some issues plotting some regression line. My problem is probably that I don't comprehend properly the mathematics done by these functions, so I'm asking here to be sure.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def estimate_coef(x, y):
    # number of observations/points
    n = np.size(x)

    # mean of x and y vector
    m_x, m_y = np.mean(x), np.mean(y)

    # calculating cross-deviation and deviation about x
    SS_xy = np.sum(y*x - n*m_y*m_x)
    SS_xx = np.sum(x*x - n*m_x*m_x)

    # calculating regression coefficients
    b_1 = SS_xy / SS_xx
    b_0 = m_y - b_1 * m_x

    return (b_0, b_1)

def plot_regression_line(xs, ys):
    # dev stands for deviation
    dev = estimate_coef(xs, ys)

    y_pred = []
    for x in xs:
        y_pred.append(dev[0] + dev[1] * x)

    # plotting the regression line
    plt.plot(xs, y_pred, color = "g")

def main():
    # Defining points.
    xarr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    yarr = [1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 12]

    # Setting points as numpy arrays.
    # It is more convenient this way for further process.
    x = np.array(xarr)
    y = np.array(yarr)

    # Plotting points.
    plt.scatter(x, y)

    plot_regression_line(x, y)
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code above shows a nicely plotted graphic, such as :

[image: Good plot]

But... if I reverse the points in my `y` axis, just to test my function, such as in the `main()` function I would do :

```
yarr = [1, 3, 2, 5, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 12]
yarr.reverse()
```

I get the following...

[image: Wrong plot]

---

I *obviously* want my `plot_regression_line` function to plot me the line I am awaiting for considering the data I input. And I can't understand why this wouldn't work.

I believe the problem comes from the `estimate_coef` function, and especially how the `b_0` is computed, but I don't know the changes I should apply in order to get my function to work as intended.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression

Comment: Thanks for the link, but as you probably know,  I had issue with the formulas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know, where you got your regression formula from. [Wikipedia has a different one.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Fitting_the_regression_line) If you transcribe it into your script conventions, it should be

```
SS_xy = np.sum((x - m_x) * (y - m_y))
SS_xx = np.sum(x*x - m_x*m_x)
```

which gives you the right regression line for both cases. And you will not need to calculate `n` any more, because it is already taken into consideration, when you calculate the mean values.

Comment: Well, I don't know where I have found the formula to be honest, I have closed the tab a long ago and can't recall where I got it from. Thanks for pointing the mistake in the formula. Since I am from a literary background, I have hard times translating pure mathematics formula into programming. I find formulas, test them, and if they work, try to find how they translate from math to prog. If they don't, I try to solve them, but this one was too much for me. :/

Comment: Glad, we solved the problem. It is actually a nice question for Math.SE or Cross Validated.SE, why your formula gives a similar (though not exactly the same) slope in one case and the negative value of it in the other.

Comment: I am already aware that I basically don't need much mathematical background to perform such operations because library like scipy (or sklearn, and bunch of others) have already implemented the maths in a good way. But I need to comprehend how the mathematics work in order to get good. ;)

Comment: Excellent answer. I am shocked, how many people here try to implement face recognition, genetic algorithms and neural network learning without being able to grasp basic mathematical concepts.

Comment: Well, another argument would be not to reinvent the wheel. And as it's already been implemented... if you don't want to work in the research field, sometimes, you'd better just learn how to use the tools researchers made for you. I wouldn't need to go as far as understanding every step of the mathematical principles, but If I understand one example from start to end, including all the matrices manipulations... I'll already be a good Data Scientist I believe. --- I have read that what's hard is the imagination. "ML is easy. Applying ML in real life is the real challenge".